# request running multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-social-login

I have this function, it calls Google social login

```
 loginnn($event){
this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
this.frmLoginGoogle.patchValue({
email: user.email,
googleAuthToken: user.authToken,
});
console.log('loop after clicking again')
});
this.loginGoogle($event);
console.log('execute the function first than the one above')

}
```

the problem is that it runs `this.loginGoogle` before the `this.socialAuthService`

I already tried to put `this.loginGoogle` inside subscribe, but it ends up running several times after a few clicks

Comment: How does `this.socialAuthService.signIn` look like?

Comment: it returns a json with the google user data

Comment: But it is an Observable?

Comment: yes, could that change something? sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: Yes, subscribe to the observable and call `loginGoogle` in that subscription. And the authState sounds like you only want to subscribe to that once at `ngOnInit` instead repeately when calling `loginn`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way to do it.

```
 this.socialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).pipe(
   switchMap(() => this.socialAuthService.authState), // switching from one to another observable after emit the value
   tap((user) => {
     this.frmLoginGoogle.patchValue({
        email: user.email,
        googleAuthToken: user.authToken,
     });
     this.loginGoogle($event);
   }),
   take(1) // limit the observable to complete after one time
 ).subscribe();
```